# Sleeper bus from Tuxtla Gutiérrez to Salina Cruz

Tags: buses, mexico, oaxaca

Is there any sleeper bus from Tuxtla Gutiérrez, Chiapas, to Salina Cruz, Oaxaca, in Mexico? How can I find out what companies operate along such routes and what the schedules are and how to book a ticket?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, bus companies such as ADO offer [service from Tuxtla Gutiérrez through Salina Cruz](https://www.ado.com.mx/viajes/ciudad-tuxtla-gutierrez-chis-a-ciudad-salina-cruz-oax/?fechaIda=16/09/2022%2000:00:00) which leave late at night. However, because the trip is "only" about six hours long, they arrive quite early in the morning. For example, on an arbitrarily-chosen date next week, there's a bus leaving at 22:40 at night and arriving 04:40 the next morning, or (a slightly fancier) one leaving at 23:50 and arriving at 05:55.